# Is there a SQL query that will always return zero results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

If there is a MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle-specific solution, I'm curious about them all.

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 0` -- try that.

Comment: `Select Top 0 * from table`

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want such a thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the DBMS, one or more of the following will work:

- `SELECT NULL LIMIT 0` (PostgreSQL and MySQL syntax) / `SELECT TOP 0 1` (MS SQL Server syntax)
- `SELECT NULL WHERE FALSE` (DBMS with a boolean type, e.g. PostgreSQL) `SELECT NULL WHERE 1=0` (most DBMSes)

For Oracle, these will need to be of the form `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL`, I believe, as you can't have `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause of some sort; not sure which versions of the `LIMIT` / `TOP` and `WHERE` it will accept.

A more elaborate option is to create a (temporary) table and not insert any rows into it, which can give you any number of columns, which will have types associated even though they contain no values:

```
-- PostgreSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE dummy ( a Int, b VarChar(42) );
SELECT * FROM dummy;

-- MS SQL Server
CREATE TABLE #DUMMY ( a Int, b VarChar(42) );
SELECT * FROM #DUMMY;
```

In PostgreSQL, you can even create a table with no columns, allowing you to have a result set with **zero rows and zero columns**:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE empty ();
SELECT * FROM empty;
```

Another possibility is if the DBMS has set-returning functions, they may be able to return an empty set. For instance, again in PostgreSQL as it's what I know best, you can give an invalid range to [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

At least in MySQL/PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 1 LIMIT 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from atable
where 1=2
```

Answer (score 2):

A where value that will always equate to something that is impossible.

```
Where 1 = 0
Where 'a' = 'b'
```

etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

There is various answers:

```
SELECT 1 LIMIT 0
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0
```

---

However, please notice that even if the number of rows is 0, the number of columns *in not*.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO t(a,b) SELECT 1 LIMIT 0;
!! Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

You have to write:

```
INSERT INTO t(a,b) SELECT 1,1 LIMIT 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can:

```
select
  * 
from
  table 
  join another_table on (false)
```

This works because in `on()` there should be boolean [expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM). With `false` the join can be never `true`.